# Get kafka message processing time

Tags: node.js, networking, apache-kafka, tcp, aiven

I have 2 services: producer and consumer.

As far as I understand, `message.ts` is the time the *producer* produced the message (***not*** the time the kafka-broker received the message).

#### Questions

1. When the *consumer* consume the message, how can I know how much time it was inside the kafka-broker (without the network latency: from producer to kafka-broker and from kafka-broker to consumer)?
2. I did a ping from my consumer vm to the kafka broker. the ping result was 0.7ms (millisecond). Does the network latency from each side to the kafka broker is 0.3ms? I assume kafka transport is `TCP` so there is a "ACK" message for everything. And I assume that each side won't do nothing without "ACK" so I conclude that the network latency on each size is the same as the ping result: 0.7ms (millisecond). ***Am I correct?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested manually this by producing and consuming from the same vm to a kafka (which was inside my cluster). The result was 1.3-1.5 ms.

It means that the procssing time took 0.1 ms on average.

- I produced a new message every 1 second to avoid delay while consuming.

This is not the best solution, but it is suffient to my research.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complicated than that. Many variables go into how long it takes to process a message. I suggest you look into Distributed Tracing. Something like [Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/) works like magic and is very easy to setup and use. Here's a [tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/distributed-tracing-with-spring-cloud-sleuth-and-spring-cloud-zipkin) on how to setup Zipkin tracing with Spring Boot. You can even use it with Kafka Connect with an interceptor, here's the one I use: [brave-kafka-interceptor](https://github.com/openzipkin-contrib/brave-kafka-interceptor).

Zipkin produces a trace for every message including all producers and consumers that processed it. Those traces end up lookin something like this:

[image]

You can see how much time a message took to be processed, and how much time it took to be consumed afte being produced, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't have yet distributed tracing. it's a great tool and I will look at that. But for now, I need answers regardless if I have distributed-tracing.